# re-enable preventDefault

Tags: jquery, click, preventdefault

I am trying to modify the href in an anchor before the click is submitted.

However the following creates an infinite loop:

```
$('.preview').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = this;
    var content = $('#redactor_content').getCode();
    var page_id = $('#page_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: ADMIN_CORE_URL + 'pages/autosave.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {page_id : page_id, content : content},
        success: function(data){
            var url = $(_this).attr('href') + data.revision_id;
            $(_this).attr('href', url);
            $(_this).unbind('click').click();
        }
    });
});
```

Either I cant get the click to submit or I get the loop.

How do I re-enable the click without the loop?

Comment: So you only want to change the href for the first click?

Comment: From the answers in this thread and elsewhere it seems that there's no way of undoing preventDefault(). We are limited to either A) Re-registering the event handler, or B) Making sure that preventDefault() is never called in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this.
that way the handler only gets executed if the link has class `x` (or whatever you want to call it).
after the ajax response, remove the class and the click handler shouldn't be executed anymore.

```
$(body).on('click', '.preview.x', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this = this;
    var content = $('#redactor_content').getCode();
    var page_id = $('#page_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: ADMIN_CORE_URL + 'pages/autosave.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {page_id : page_id, content : content},
        success: function(data){
            var url = $(_this).attr('href') + data.revision_id;


            // $(_this).attr('href', url);
            // $(_this).removeClass('x').click();
            //
            // edit: version 2:
            window.open(url);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like that but doesn't that mean the link could only ever be pressed once?

Comment: @AsaCarter well yeah, isn't that what you want? I thought you want change the href on the link after the ajax, then load that href like a regular click (just a normal page redirect, no preventDefault + jquery). If not, please be more specific on what your actual goal is.

Comment: sorry the link opens in a new window so it could be clicked again.

Comment: @AsaCarter Aha! so in that case, why don't you just do `window.open(url);` instead of changing the href of the link?

Comment: Because I want to avoid issues with pop up blockers

Comment: This is the only way I can get it working. It sucks that I cant just amend the href and then send the click on its way again.

Answer (score 0):

It's looping I assume because the `unbind()` is not doing what you expect and then you're manually forcing the link to be clicked everytime the ajax call succeeds, which presumably runs the same bit of code again and again.

Take away the extra `.click()` and work out how to unbind the original click correctly first, then add the `click()` back in if you need it. As a side note, since you're using `live()` to bind, it would make more sense to use `.die()` to unbind (These two methods have since been replaced with the `.on()` and `.off()` API too)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(_this).unbind('click').click();
```

with

```
$(_this).off('click');
```

As of jquery 1.7.2 `.live` is deprecated and [.on](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) is used

```
$('body').on('click','.preview', handler);
```

After unbinding, you are triggering a click event by `.click()`.

Removing that should solve the issue

**EDIT**

```
var handler = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var _this = this;
    alert('called');
    $(_this).off('click').on(handler);
}


$('body').on('click','.preview', handler);
```

Use .on() to attach an event handler and [.off()](http://jqapi.com/#p=off) to remove it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/NGhvn/1/)**

Hope this helps

Comment: in that case you can attach the handler again

Comment: Thanks, could you amend the demo with the link clicking after changing the value of the url? I still cant get the link to click :(

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt click ? Could you please explain more

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12866/discussion-between-dhiraj-bodicherla-and-asa-carter)